# Inject beans from other projects into Vaadin view

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In one of my Vaadin views I'm trying to get hold of a business object that resides in another project (bll) by injecting it with @Inject.

Vaadin view:

```
public class FruitSaladView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    @Inject
    BananaService bananaService;
...
}
```

I can't do this, of course, the bananaService object is null at runtime, because I have nowhere to do a component-scan for packages.

I'm using annotations so I have no web.xml in my Vaadin web project, I don't even have a WEB-INF folder.

I also know there are some alternatives, like the [CDI-Utils](http://vaadin.com/addon/cdi-utils) and the [Vaadin CDI](http://vaadin.com/addon/vaadin-cdi) Vaadin addons, as well as [some other](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20JEE6%20Vaadin%20Applications) solutions to this, but they all seem to inject stuff into the Main UI (not to the views) and from the web application itself, not from other modules.

I'm using Vaadin 7 and Tomcat 7 (as long as it's feasible using Tomcat given the answer to the question below)

**Question:** What would be the recommended way to inject a bean from another module into a Vaadin view and what do I need to do in order to accomplish this?

**Follow-up question:** Will using Tomcat for this application be a problem after using above method?

Comment: Convert your other project to a jar. Put in your current project classpath. I don't know Vaadin but there must be a place where you have access to the IoC container. Declare your bean there.

Comment: That is the problem. I cannot access the IoC container, because I don't know how or where to do it. In the other projects I'm injecting successfully using @Inject in code and component-scan in the context.xml. Vaadin doesn't use a context.xml per-se.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is just Servlet container, if you want use CDI you must use JEE6 compliant server, like tomee or jboss.
If you are interested in best practices for integration Vaadin and CDI, I recommend you start with: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/essential_vaadin_7_java_ee

You wrote that you want inject beans Vaadin views directly. Analyze example code https://github.com/vaadin/cdi/blob/master/vaadin-cdi-example/src/main/java/com/vaadin/cdi/example/view/RootView.java to learn how to do it with vaadin-cdi add-on

Comment: Thanks! I know about the Vaadin-CDI addon. If I could, I would much rather use a method that doesn't require a full application server. I want to use Tomcat. Is there another option to CDI/EJB if I want to @Inject/@Autowired a bean to a Vaadin view class, or is that the best recommendation for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Roger, I think you should open you mind for application server. If you like Tomcat, check TomEE.
But if you really like Tomcat only, read this solution: http://www.lucubratory.eu/getting-weld-cdi-into-tomcat-7/